# Altium Designer multi sheet design quad op amp

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I have to design an multi channel sampling device: there is an input stage with some filters, then digitization of them and some supplementary circuit.

To create a filter, I want to use quad op amp, but one channel needs only 1 from the package. And I want to represent my design on subsheets, each sheet contains only 1 channel.

Can anybody help me how can I instruct Altium Designer to recognize that op amps in every four sheet belongs to the same package?

Comment: Are you okay with having a separate schematic document for each channel or do you want to use multiple instances of one schematic document for the 4 channels?

Comment: How many channels? If only 4, then multi-sheet is overkill. Otherwise, put 4 channels on your subsheet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is a multiple part symbol, they allow you to split one package or part into subparts. There is a great tutorial at altium that [describes how to do this](https://resources.altium.com/pcb-design-blog/in-your-altium-library-multiple-part-symbols-ease-your-design-time)

After you create a part that has multiple parts, you can place the parts anywhere in your design and altium will recognize the part as the same part as long as you keep the designatior the same. The designator will also have have the subpart letter in the part name. For example: a part with U3 with an A and B subpart has designators U3A and U3B

[image]
Source: https://resources.altium.com/pcb-design-blog/in-your-altium-library-multiple-part-symbols-ease-your-design-time

Comment: The problem is you need to put part A in one channel, B in the other channel, etc., which forces you to have a separate schematic sheet for each channel rather than using fully hierarchical design.

Comment: This is, how I organize the component. 
On the other hand: Let's say, I have a low pass filter design on a subsheet which consumes only 1 amplifier. I use sheet symbol with the REPEAT macro to generate such an amplifier for 10 channels, but I want only use 5 dual op amp (considering your example).

Comment: Using subparts across sheets could probably be done, but all of the labeling would need to be done by hand, you could not use a repeat statement. You might try using a subsheet for subparts A and B with a repeat and a subsheet for parts C and D, that might work.